# Opengl: Use single channel texture as alpha channel to display text

Tags: c++, opengl, text, opengl-4

What I'm trying to do is load a texture into hardware from a single channel data array and use it's alpha channel to draw text onto an object.  I am using opengl 4.

If I try to do this using a 4 channel RGBA texture it works perfectly fine but for whatever reason when I try and load in a single channel only I get a garbled image and I can't figure out why.
I create the texture by combing texture bitmap data for a series of glyphs with the following code into a single texture:

```
int texture_height = max_height * new_font->num_glyphs;
int texture_width = max_width;

new_texture->datasize = texture_width * texture_height;
unsigned char* full_texture = new unsigned char[new_texture->datasize];

// prefill texture as transparent
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < new_texture->datasize; j++)
    full_texture[j] = 0;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < glyph_textures.size(); i++) {
    // set height offset for glyph
    new_font->glyphs[i].height_offset = max_height * i;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < new_font->glyphs[i].height; j++) {
        int full_disp = (new_font->glyphs[i].height_offset + j) * texture_width;
        int bit_disp = j * new_font->glyphs[i].width;
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < new_font->glyphs[i].width; k++) {
            full_texture[(full_disp + k)] =
                    glyph_textures[i][bit_disp + k];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I load the texture data calling:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture->x, texture->y, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(full_texture));
```

My fragment shader executes the following code:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec4 pass_colour;

out vec4 out_colour;

void main()
{
float temp = texture2D(texture, texcoord).r;
out_colour = vec4(pass_colour[0], pass_colour[1], pass_colour[2], temp);
}
```

I get an image that I can tell is generated from the texture but it is terribly distorted and I'm unsure why.  Btw I'm using GL_RED because GL_ALPHA was removed from Opengl 4.
What really confuses me is why this works fine when I generate a 4 RGBA texture from the glyphs and then use it's alpha channel??

Comment: In the end I've gotten this to work by converting data to float before calling glTexImage2D.  I believe I am required to use a data format that is a multiple of 4 bytes.  That is why RGBA to RGBA worked (even though it's 4x byte) and why float data works as well.  It seems I am unable to use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE unless it's with both input and output in 4 channel data.  Maybe this is a bug in ATI drivers??

Comment: Okay I've figured this out.  There was nothing wrong with my code nor a bug in the driver. GL_UNPACK_ALINGMENT needs to be set to 1 for this to work.  It's set to 4 by default.  Running "glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);" fixxed all my issues.  I'm unsure why it's set to 4 maybe for performance reasons.  I will investigate.

Answer (score 15):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture->x, texture->y, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(full_texture));
```

This is technically legal but *never* a good idea.

First, you need to understand what the third parameter to `glTexImage2D` is. That's the actual [*image format*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format) of the texture. You are not creating a texture with one channel; you're creating a texture with *four* channels.

Next, you need to understand what the last three parameters do. These are the [pixel transfer parameters](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer); they describe what the pixel data you're giving to OpenGL looks like.

This command is saying, "create a 4 channel texture, then upload some data to *just* the red channel. This data is stored as an array of unsigned bytes." Uploading data to only *some* of the channels of a texture is technically legal, but almost never a good idea. If you're creating a single-channel texture, you should use a *single-channel texture*. And that means a proper image format.

Next, things get more confusing:

```
new_texture->datasize = texture_width * texture_height*4;
```

Your use of "*4" strongly suggests that you're creating four-channel pixel data. But you're only uploading one-channel data. The rest of your computations agree with this; you don't seem to ever fill in any data pass `full_texture[texture_width * texture_height]`. So you're probably allocating more memory than you need.

One last thing: *always* use sized internal formats. Never just use `GL_RGBA`; use `GL_RGBA8` or `GL_RGBA4` or whatever. Don't let the driver pick and hope it gives you a good one.

So, the correct upload would be this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, texture->x, texture->y, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, full_texture);
```

FYI: the `reinterpret_cast` is unnecessary; even in C++, pointers can implicitly be converted into `void*`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info.  The 4 was a typo from when I was switching back and forth between loading 4 channels and 1 channel.  I messed up when posting and I'll edit the post.  I've applied all your suggestions and unfortunately I still get the same effect.

Comment: It's very strange I get the proper effect when I create a 4 channel texture from 4 channel data nut if I try to create a 1 channel texture from 4 channel data it still messes up!  This at least tells me that the issue isn't the input data and must lie downstream either in the conversion from one type of data to another or in my shader code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you swapped the "internal format" and "format" parameters of glTexImage2d().  That is, you told it that you want RGBA in the texture object, but only had RED in the file data rather than vice-versa.

Try to replace your call with the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, texture->x, texture->y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, reinterpret_cast<void*>(full_texture));
```

Comment: My filedata is Red and the internal data in RGBA.  If I swap them it's worse.  I've also tried setting both the internal file data to RED and it still displays the same...  I've even tried taking in two channels and that doesn't work as well...